# How to achieve an adaptive layout where items resize in a grid to fit as you add items?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to accomplish a layout where as i add items to the collection the items display smaller in a grid such that:

With 1 item it is full screen
With 2 it is full screen
With 3 each item is 1/3 of the screen
With the 4th it adds a row and does it again at 7 10 etc elements

So that with 6 elements the result is the same as a wrapgrid with maxcolumn = 3 but with less than 3 the items still take all of the size (it's to display pictures for selection, so if there are less pictures i want them to be bigger, and the 1 or 2 picture scenario is a common one in my case).

Edit: A good example of what i'm trying to achieve is WPF's UniformGrid whose layout adapts as you add items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this effect. Below is a solution by using ViewBox and GridView.

In XAML(You can change the Rectangle to a IMAGE with the binding IconUri):

```
<Viewbox x:Name="box">
    <GridView x:Name="test" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxHeight="800" MaxWidth="800" Grid.Column="1" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                       Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <Rectangle Width="100" Height="30" Fill="Red" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IconUri}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Name}' 
                               Foreground="Black" Margin="30"
                               Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
</Viewbox>
```

In CS:

```
 cvsProjects = new List<Project>();
 Project item0 = new Project() { Name = "pic1", IconUri = "Images/p1.jpg"};
 Project item1 = new Project() { Name = "pic2", IconUri = "Images/p2.jpg" };
 Project item2 = new Project() { Name = "pic3", IconUri = "Images/p3.jpg" };
 Project item3 = new Project() { Name = "pic4", IconUri = "Images/p4.jpg" };
 Project item4 = new Project() { Name = "pic5", IconUri = "Images/p5.jpg" };
 Project item5 = new Project() { Name = "pic6", IconUri = "Images/p6.jpg" };
 cvsProjects.Add(item0);
 cvsProjects.Add(item1);
 cvsProjects.Add(item2);
 cvsProjects.Add(item3);
 cvsProjects.Add(item4);
 cvsProjects.Add(item5);
 test.ItemsSource = cvsProjects;
```

Comment: Thanks, using a viewbox was the solution to all my problems!